# Is it possible to splice this garage door safety sensor wire with some other wire?

Tags: garage-door-opener, wire

I currently have these sensors:

[http://www.amazon.com/Chamberlain-Liftmaster-41A4373A-Safety-Sensors/dp/B00283Q9AW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00283Q9AW)

An accident occurred a few days ago and the cable to the receiver was snapped apart.  I am going to replace the opener in a few years anyway and don't feel like buying and installing two new sensors (would have to run the wires, align the sensors, bleh).

If I could buy some wire and splice it to this one then that would be awesome.  However, I don't know what kind of wire to buy.  Someone please let me know if I can do this.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a low voltage sensor, so I'd just use some two conductor [thermostat wire](http://www.amazon.com/Southwire-64162122-Conductor-Thermostat-Power-Limited/dp/B0069F4H0E). If there's anything that indicates that it operates at 120VAC line voltage, then the low voltage thermostat wire would not be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Garage door sensors and buttons are low voltage (usually 24vdc), and low enough current that for the short runs typical in a garage you don't need very large cables.

18awg "thermostat wire" will work, but you can go even cheaper with 22awg wire, usually sold as "security system" or "central vac" wiring (2 conductor), or telephone station wire (4 conductor - though you only hook up two).

[image: central vac wire]
[image: security/speaker wire]
[image: station wire]

Also, a little bit of heat shrink tubing goes a long way to making a neat and professional looking splice.

[image: heat shrink tubing]

Comment: An old bit of leftover wire will do, maybe some junk electronics.  It really won't matter, in this case it need not even be as thick as the original.

Comment: [Chamberlain](http://chamberlain.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4119) recommends 22 gauge bell wire.